# show that $t \leq \pi\sin(t/2)$ for $0 < t < \pi$?

Tags: calculus

show that $t \leq \pi*\sin(t/2)$ for $0 < t < \pi$?

I am able to just graph both of their graphs and see that this is true but how do i solve it algebraically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that $$f(t)=\pi\sin(t/2)-t\geq 0$$
if $t\in[0,\pi]$.

Comment: sin(t/2) is always a positive number for 0 < t < π so when you multiply sin(t/2) by π you will always get a bigger number than t or something equal to t because the biggest number t can be is π. is this correct? the thing is i dont know how to sho that algebraically, i know how to explain it in words

Comment: $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$. Moreover $f'(t)=\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(t/2)-1=0$ has a unique solution in $[0,\pi]$ since $x\mapsto \cos(\frac{x}{2})$ is injective on $[0,\pi]$ and Rolle's theorem tell us that there exist a $c\in]0,\pi[$ s.t. $f'(c)=0$. Finally, we get that $f'(x)>0$ if $0\leq x< c$ and $f'(x)<0$ if $\pi\geq x>c$, therefore, we get the result.